# How do I input a node P and output should be the node after P as per pre-order, in-order & post-Order traversal method?

Tags: python

For example if pre-order travsersal of a tree is (1,2,3,4,5,6) and I input 4 to this method, my output should be 5 and 6.

This is my current method of preOrder,inOrder and postOrder traversal.

```
def in_order_traversal(self):
    elements = []
    if self.left:
        elements += self.left.in_order_traversal()

    elements.append(self.data)

    if self.right:
        elements += self.right.in_order_traversal()

    return elements

def post_order_traversal(self):
    elements = []
    if self.left:
        elements += self.left.post_order_traversal()
    if self.right:
        elements += self.right.post_order_traversal()

    elements.append(self.data)

    return elements

def pre_order_traversal(self):
    elements = [self.data]
    if self.left:
        elements += self.left.pre_order_traversal()
    if self.right:
        elements += self.right.pre_order_traversal()

    return elements
```

Comment: After your traversal, you can use ```index``` method to find the element location and then print the elements present after that location.  So, if elements is your result ```list```, get elements.index(4), and iterate over the rest of the list.

Comment: can you help how to code it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you got the list of nodes in a list variable named list1, use below code snippet.

```
#find the position of your input data
pos = list1.index(3)

#start from the node next to the input node 
i=pos+1

#find the length, so that we don't exceed
listLen=len(list1)
while i < listLen:
  print(list1[i])  #print the node
  i+=1   #increment to go to next node
```

Comment: Thank you! it works fine. I just want to ask one more question is it possible if I pass the node through the method such as in_order_traversal(3)? For example,
Node = 3
print("Post order traversal:", numbers_tree.post_order_traversal(3))

Comment: You should receive that node value as input argument in an outer function, and need not pass to the recursive function.

Comment: okay noted. But what if my function is not recursive but iterative?

Comment: about your code, how do you modify to get the next node only? lets say list = [5,9,2,4,3] and I input Node = 9, only  2 will be output.

Comment: if you only need the next node, then you can avoid the loop. after finding the position, you just need to increment it once and you have your output node.

Comment: oh okay, can you help how to implement it on the above method?